# Python Selenium Firefox geckodriver. Detach browser from terminal

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, ubuntu-20.04

With Chrome (chromedriver) it's very simple:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
```

With Firefox (geckodriver) no:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)  # Returns syntax error
```

What is the equivalent syntax for leaving the Firefox browser open even when the script ends?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlying structure of Chrome (chromedriver) and Firefox (geckodriver) are different.

For example the *add_experimental_option* exists in *chromedriver*
[image]

This *add_experimental_option* does not exist in *geckodriver*, so that is why you are getting an error.

[image]

I have looked through various *geckodriver* documents and haven't seen a reference similar to this one from *chromedriver.*

[image]

*Please note the options_spec.rb code below is from the Ruby source
code for selenium.*

The code below is from the file *options_spec.rb*, which is part of the *selenium* source code for *chromedriver.*  Note the *detach: true* in the dictionary.

```
opts = Options.new(browser_version: '75',
                   platform_name: 'win10',
                   accept_insecure_certs: false,
                   page_load_strategy: 'eager',
                   unhandled_prompt_behavior: 'accept',
                   strict_file_interactability: true,
                   timeouts: {script: 40000,
                              page_load: 400000,
                              implicit: 1},
                   set_window_rect: false,
                   args: %w[foo bar],
                   prefs: {foo: 'bar'},
                   binary: '/foo/bar',
                   extensions: ['foo.crx', 'bar.crx'],
                   encoded_extensions: ['encoded_foobar'],
                   foo: 'bar',
                   emulation: {device_name: :bar},
                   local_state: {foo: 'bar'},
                   detach: true,
                   debugger_address: '127.0.0.1:8181',
                   exclude_switches: %w[foobar barfoo],
                   minidump_path: 'linux/only',
                   perf_logging_prefs: {enable_network: true},
                   window_types: %w[normal devtools],
                   'custom:options': {foo: 'bar'})
```

The code below is from the file *options_spec.rb*, which is part of the *selenium* source code for *geckodriver.*  Note there is no *detach: true* in the dictionary.

```
opts = Options.new(browser_version: '66',
                   platform_name: 'win10',
                   accept_insecure_certs: false,
                   page_load_strategy: 'eager',
                   unhandled_prompt_behavior: 'accept',
                   strict_file_interactability: true,
                   timeouts: {script: 40000,
                              page_load: 400000,
                              implicit: 1},
                   set_window_rect: false,
                   args: %w[foo bar],
                   binary: '/foo/bar',
                   prefs: {foo: 'bar'},
                   foo: 'bar',
                   profile: profile,
                   log_level: :debug,
                   'custom:options': {foo: 'bar'})
```

The code below is from the file *options_spec.rb*, which is part of the *selenium* source code for *edgedriver.*  Note there is a *detach: true* in the dictionary.

```
opts = Options.new(browser_version: '75',
                   platform_name: 'win10',
                   accept_insecure_certs: false,
                   page_load_strategy: 'eager',
                   unhandled_prompt_behavior: 'accept',
                   strict_file_interactability: true,
                   timeouts: {script: 40000,
                              page_load: 400000,
                              implicit: 1},
                   set_window_rect: false,
                   args: %w[foo bar],
                   prefs: {foo: 'bar'},
                   binary: '/foo/bar',
                   extensions: ['foo.crx', 'bar.crx'],
                   encoded_extensions: ['encoded_foobar'],
                   foo: 'bar',
                   emulation: {device_name: :bar},
                   local_state: {foo: 'bar'},
                   detach: true,
                   debugger_address: '127.0.0.1:8181',
                   exclude_switches: %w[foobar barfoo],
                   minidump_path: 'linux/only',
                   perf_logging_prefs: {enable_network: true},
                   window_types: %w[normal devtools],
                   'custom:options': {foo: 'bar'})
```

Based on the dictionaries in these 3 option files, one would assume that *{'detach': True}* isn't an option in the *geckodriver.*

The *options.py* for the *geckodriver* in the Python *selenium* structure is different than the Ruby file *options_spec.rb*.

```
def preferences(self) -> dict:
       """:Returns: A dict of preferences."""
       return self._preferences

def set_preference(self, name: str, value: Union[str, int, bool]):
       """Sets a preference."""
       self._preferences[name] = value
```

When looking through the source code for the Python *geckodriver* in Mozilla's gecko-dev GitHub repository I saw that I could query pre-defined preferences and capabilities.

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
firefox_options = Options()

print(firefox_options.arguments)
# output
['--test-type', '--ignore-certificate-errors', '--disable-infobars', '--disable-extensions', '--disable-popup-blocking']

print(firefox_options.capabilities)
# output
{'browserName': 'firefox', 'marionette': True, 'acceptInsecureCerts': True}

print(firefox_options.preferences)
# output
{'detach': True}
```

So {'detach': True} is an option in the *geckodriver,* so you should be able to set the option this way:

```
firefox_options.set_preference('detach', True)
```

Comment: This is the right command but it doesn't work. It takes a bug report. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you never call `driver.close()`, the browser window will stay open and you can examine/use it however you like. Have you tried this?

Comment: My goal is that the sudden closure of the terminal using GeckoDriver must have the same effect as it has with ChromeDriver, i.e. not to close the browser, instead ChromeDriver and GeckoDriver have two opposite behaviors to the sudden closure of the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You need only this, thanks to @Life is complex

So {'detach': True} is an option in the geckodriver, so you should be able to set the option this way:

```
firefox_options.set_preference('detach', True)
```